# What is the middle button in Gnome system menu for?

Tags: gnome, menu

I have updated to Ubuntu 16.04.1 and Gnome 3.18.5. There is a new button in the system menu, below where my username is written. It is located between the Settings button and the power-off button.
When I click it it does nothing and no help text is shown.

What is this button for?

[image: Screenshot of my system menu]

Comment: A screenshot please? At leas describe what it looks like.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. The middle button on the bottom is the button in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling that icon shows [this post from Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/84944/what-is-this-new-button-in-the-settings-menu/):

> Enables/Disables Screen Rotation for devices that can figure out which
>   way they are being held.

Comment: or a "rotation lock" that can be disabled as this post on Ask Fedora https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/76596/unknown-gnome-menu-icon/?answer=76599#post-id-76599on

Comment: @souravc yes, the post I linked to is closed as a dupe of that.

Comment: Thanks muru, I tried to google it but could not name it correctly.

Comment: @domih neither could I. I cropped out the icon and used [Google's Image search](https://google.com/imghp).